# How to read specific scenario in a feature file using * def result = call read('classpath:some-reusable-steps.feature')?

Tags: karate

- def result = call read('classpath:some-reusable-steps.feature')

I have multiple scenarios in a feature file but i have to read a specific scenario in it?
please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#call-tag-selector

```
* def result = call read('classpath:some-reusable-steps.feature@sometag')
```

Comment: I tried as specified in the documentation but i get below error:

com.intuit.karate - not a js function or feature file: read('classpath:some-reusable-steps.feature@name=delete') - [type: NULL, value: null]

Comment: @Vindhiyan okay, time for you to follow this process please, all the best: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: The difference i see is - i have provide complete class path
How do i make it work if have complete path name?
call read('classpath:com/vindhiyan/feature/some-reusable-steps.feature@name=delete')

Comment: follow. the. instructions

Comment: It worked after updating to the latest version 0.9.4
Earlier i was using 0.7.0